# How can I use compass inline-image helper with an image url that is not relative?

Tags: css, compass-sass

## Problem

How can I use compass **[inline-image helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/)** with an image url that is *not* relative?

### config.rb

```
relative_assets = false
```

I also tried commenting that out completely

### This code works

**hdr-main.png** lives in the **/test/images/** on my local Server.

```
.test{
$image:"hdr-main.png";
background: inline-image($image);
}
```

### This code does *not* work

```
.test{
$image:"http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.png";
background: inline-image($image);
}
```

### Displays this error

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:
File not found or cannot be read: /Users/myname/test/images/http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is since you haven't actually asked a question. You have working code and I'm assuming you're trying to render a production stylesheet as well.

You should probably leave `$image: "hdr-main.png"` as-is then use config.rb to set your `http_images_path` to `http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/`.

You'll want to probably use this in conjunction with setting the `environment` to production.

```
if environment == :production
  http_images_path = "http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/"
end
```

then you'd build your CSS with the following

`compass compile -e production`

Again, this is assumption since there isn't a clear question posted above. If this isn't what you need, please ask a specific question.

Comment: Should I remove `images_dir = "img"` from the config.rb?

Comment: that's not the issue, you just can't inline a remote image (I think). If you want to inline it, just use a local path to it on your system.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Compass online documentation for [inline-image](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/#inline-image) :

> the path specified should be relative to your project's images directory