# Compass inline-image syntax/configuration

Tags: css, extjs, sass, compass, sencha-fashion

I add the following block to `myapp.scss`:

```
.resourceType2 { 
    background: url('../resources/ressource2.png') no-repeat 2px 1px; 
    padding-left: 16px; 
}
```

After I call `sencha app build production` with Cmd 6.0.1.76, I see the background-image. I found that you can use `inline-image` and compass should make css inline images from your images. So I add to `myapp.scss` instead:

```
.resourceType2 { 
    background: inline-image('../resources/ressource2.png') no-repeat 2px 1px; 
    padding-left: 16px; 
}
```

After successful build, I don't see the images.

I found that `MyApp-all.css` still contains `inline-image('../resources/ressource2.png')`, just as if it wouldn't replace them properly. Am I missing some config option required to enable inline-image generation?

Comment: Which object are you trying to style?

Comment: @Tarabass I am trying to get rid of the 100+ icon files for all the button `iconCls` properties.

Comment: As I can read at the following link you have to configure a http_images_path in config.rb (can be found in the sass folder of your app). Don't know if it's a solution, just wanted to share http://stackoverflow.com/a/19406012/408487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the [SenchaCon roadshow agenda](http://roadshow.senchacon.com/de/switzerland/zurich#agenda-section), I more or less stumbled upon the answer.

**Summary:**

Cmd 6.0.1 does not use sass or compass any longer. It uses Sencha Fashion, which takes sass files and compiles them. Sencha Fashion does have support for sass variables, but not for compass helpers written in Ruby, because the goal was to remove the Ruby dependency. Instead, one would have to rewrite the required helpers as Sencha Fashion extensions in JavaScript.

<strike>I have yet to find a list of available/builtin "extensions" and a full guide how to write my own.</strike> There are no javascript extensions available in the ext package as of now. There is no documentation available with all builtin SASS functions and their parameters, you can only find them by searching through the original scss files delivered with ExtJS.

**Extension example:**

If you want to have an extension that converts resource images to their data uri equivalent, you could put the following code into your `sass/src` directory, e.g. as `inlineimage.js`:

```
exports.init = function(runtime) {
    if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
        String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) { 
            return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - ((suffix && suffix.length) || 0)) !== -1; 
        };
    }
    function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
        }
        return window.btoa( binary );
    }
    runtime.register({
        inlineImage: function (uri, mime) {
            // URI has the keys: value,unit,quoteChar,splat
            // URI has the values: ../../resources/delete.gif,,',
            if(!mime) {
                if(uri.value.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) mime = "image/png";
                else if(uri.value.toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")) mime = "image/gif";
                else if(uri.value.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) mime = "image/jpeg";
                else if(uri.value.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) mime = "image/jpeg";
            }
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', uri.value, false); 
            xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            xhr.send(null);
            if(xhr.status==404) throw new Error("Inline image source " + uri.value + " not found");
            uri.value="url(data:"+mime+";base64,"+_arrayBufferToBase64(xhr.response)+")";
            uri.quoteChar="";
            return uri;
        }
    });
};
```

In your scss file, for instance `sass/src/view/Viewport.scss`, you would then write:

```
require("../inlineimage.js");
.icon-checklist {
    background: inlineImage('../images/checklist.png') no-repeat center center !important;
}
```

The image in this case would be located in `sass/images`, so that cmd won't copy it into the output `resource` folder (it should only show up in the output CSS file).

The `inlineImage` in the scss file now refers to the registered javascript function `inlineImage`, which will be executed to download the image and return it as a data uri.

**Sources:**

- [What's new in ExtJS6: Sencha Fashion](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/whats_new/6.0.0/fashion.html)
- [How to style apps with Fashion](http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/how-to-style-apps-with-fashion-in-ext-js-6/)
- [How to style apps with Fashion (Alternate source)](https://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-style-apps-with-fashion-in-ext-js-6/)
- [Sencha Forum question: Where to find Sencha Fashion apidocs/specs?](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305613-Sencha-Fashion-apidocs-specs), now trying to evolve it into a "let us make a sample extension" thread.

Comment: I see you are a premium member. Why not open a ticket for this? And as you can see I putted a bounty on this one, so I would be interested to hear the outcome..

Comment: Well, I think I will wait with the ticket until I have attended the roadshow and asked them face to face. It's not an urgent matter right now.

Comment: @Tarabass I found the time to extend my answer a bit.

Comment: Thx for the update. I think they (Sencha) are going a bit to fast with Fashion. The idea is very good, but as long as there are no alternatives for some things and with the lack of decent documentation I still install Cmd with Ruby included.

Comment: @Tarabass To prevent that, they have made the new ExtJS6 style sheets incompatible with compass. As per 6.0.2, you cannot compile the default ExtJS themes with compass.